# Convert Nested Operations to Use Cases

Tags: r, dplyr, igraph

Input:
input1: operations.csv

```
| id   | operation   | sub_start_id   | sub_return_id   | eq_parent_id   |
| ---- | ----------- | -------------- | --------------- | -------------- |
| 1    | x           | NA             | NA              | NA             |
| 2    | x1          | 4              | NA              | 1              |
| 3    | x2          | NA             | NA              | 1              |
| 4    | k           | NA             | NA              | NA             |
| 5    | k1          | NA             | NA              | 4              |
| 6    | k2          | NA             | NA              | 4              |
| 7    | L           | NA             | 2               | NA             |
| 8    | L1          | NA             | NA              | 7              |
| 9    | L2          | NA             | NA              | 7              |
| 10   | L3          | NA             | NA              | 7              |
```

input2: operation_relations.csv

```
| from   | to   |
| ------ | ---- |
| NA     | 1    |
| 2      | 3    |
| 4      | 7    |
| 5      | 6    |
| 8      | 9    |
| 8      | 10   |
```

here's the code for the 2 input data frame:

```
nodes <- data.frame("id" = 1:10, 
                    "operation" = c('X', 'X1', 'X2', 'K', 'K1', 'K2', 'L', 'L1', 'L2', 'L3'),
                    "sub_start_id" = c(NA, 4, rep(NA, 8)),
                    "sub_return_id" = c(rep(NA, 6), 2, rep(NA, 3)),
                    "eq_parent_id" = c(NA, 1, 1, NA, 4, 4, NA, 7, 7, 7))

links = data.frame("from" = c(NA, 2, 4, 5, 8, 8),
                   "to"   = c(1, 3, 7, 6, 9, 10))
```

I need the output to be like that:

Expected Output:

use case for top level

```
1. x
```

use case for x

```
1. x1
2. x2
```

use case for x1

```
1. k
2. L
```

use case for k

```
1. k1
2. k2
```

use case for L

```
1. L1
2. L2
3. L3
```

How to do this in R, and is there a way to represent it using igraph?
Please have a look on the image link below for a better visualization of the problem.

[nested operations photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKAHB.jpg)